# how to reduce vertical space before parts and increase chapter size in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize, include, vertical-spacing

currently writing a Geometry textbook and the start of the table of contents looks like this:

[image]

With this code, using the tocloft package for my TOC: [image]

Edit: Here is what the beginning of each chapter file looks like:

[image]

I would like to reduce the vertical space between "Contents" and "Part I", and make the chapter titles have larger text than the sections below them, but I tried adding "\large" before the text in \chapter{Basic Concepts...} and it didn't work, it only made the text on the actual page smaller.  Does anyone know how to do this with included chapter files?  Thanks in advance.

Edit: the titlesec and sectsty packages look promising but their descriptions don't explain exactly what their commands do and don't change.  Does anyone have experience using these packages for this purpose?

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add a Minimal Working Example, i.e. a copy/pastable document where you remove all unessary lines that showcase your issue? It will save precious time to people wanting to help you.

Comment: If you edit your original question please indicate the edits, otherwise we will have no idea about your problem and how to help you.

Comment: What have you put in "ch1" etc that you include? Perhaps they are the cause of your problem. I suggest you read your question as you proposed it and than consider how you, or any one else, might try  and answer based on the information you provided. We are not mind readers even if you think you are. --- GOM

Comment: I figured out the second part.  Use \renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\LARGE\bfseries}\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\large\bfseries}